# Exception thrown when running unit test

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I'm implementing the quickstart features of [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) as a learning exercise by creating a simple console application. When I run the app I see the exception.

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public bool DoSomething(string value)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static Mock<IFoo> mock = new Mock<IFoo>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("reset")).Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
      Assert.That(() => mock.Object.DoSomething("reset"), 
          Throws.InvalidOperationException);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class `Foo` does not have any dependencies... so you don't need to mock anything to test that class. You should simply create object of Foo by doing `var foo = new Foo();`

Comment: What do you do here? Are you mocking the System Under Test? What do you **really** want to test?

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a `Moq` problem, more a *I can't catch the exception thrown in `DoSomething` problem*. I will assume that you use the `nunit` framework.

Try to use the [built in method Assert.Throws](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.Throws.html) for exception assertion

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(
      () => { mock.Object.DoSomething("reset"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you run unit tests as part of an application and you are in debug mode you will see the exception being thrown as a popup dialog.  Same as using the test running in debug mode.  Running in release mode does not show the exception.